# Updating MS SQL Tools/ODBC Driver for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, updates, mssql

I've recently updated my MS SQL Server (R) Instance on my Ubuntu 18.04 box with the newest (for Ubuntu) MS SQL Server version 17. That went fine.

But as I used the Software Updater to update the package `ODBC Driver for Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R)`, I've ended with an error message telling me the package has unsatisfied dependencies and was not updated. I'm using the Bionic-repository ([18.04](https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list)) for the MS SQL Server Tools and ODBC Driver and the Xenial-repository ([16.04](https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list)) for the MS SQL Server packages...

So why the package failed to update?

To share my experience with that, here is the solution I've used to overcome the problem...

I wanted to know what exactly is wrong with the package (*msodbcsql17*). So I've run manually the package update from the terminal:

`sudo apt-get install msodbcsql17`

And I was presented with an old-style in-terminal char-graphical dialog box, asking me to confirm that I accept the Terms and License Conditions for this package... I was not sure if the `-y` switch of the apt-get command would help for the customized dialog box, so I've just tapped on *Yes* and the package installed successfully - no errors, no warnings, no failures.

So that was it! For me, this seems to be a package design glitch, as it makes the package unusable in unattended installations, such like those with the SU, because the package installation just hangs on that old-style dialog box and I'm not able to *convince* the installer to continue (the dialog box does not appear on the terminal attached to the SU).

I hope this solution can save other people's time when battling the ODBC Driver for MS SQL Server (R) updates on Ubuntu.

To the people with more rights: as I'm a real newbie in this forum, I'm unable to mark this *question* as contribution, so please mark/move it if appropriate... Thanks!